# CRM Dynamics Same workflow Different Entity

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-2013

I have several entities which have 3 common fields amongst all of them (same name spelling and everything). I have a workflow that has a certain amount of steps that operate on these 3 fields. During workflow creation you target an entity to the workflow so it can operate on. I require the exact same workflow but simply to target the other entities that are setup exactly the same way. Is there a way i can duplicate the first workflow i made and replicate it and simply change the target entity without having to re create the exact same workflow targeting different entities (there are a lot of steps). I understand even though the field names are same amongst the workflows internally they are different. If anyone has a suggestion to how i should approach this i would appreciate it.

Comment: No way. You have to recreate.

Comment: I like Daryl shortcut below. But too risky.. If you are going to follow Daryl idea, take a solution backup, database backup. This is not only going to deal with xml schema but also DB records in async operations table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create a solution with just the single workflow in it, export it and extract it and attempt to replace all of the references to the other entity as well as rename it and then pack it back up and reimport it.

It should be possible, but I wouldn't recommend it unless the workflow is crazy complicated.

Answer (score 0):

We have workflow templates. This is useful for creating steps & save as template within the same entity. So we can reuse the template while creating workflows for the same entity with less efforts.

http://www.powerobjects.com/2013/12/27/microsoft-dynamics-crm-workflow-templates/

But your question is regarding WF template across entities. So it's impossible in supported way.

You have to recreate the WF.